# What is the error in "He came by foot"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> "He came by foot": correct the error.

What is the error? I guess it is not about 'on foot' vs 'by foot' as some articles show that both are correct, though I am not sure.

Comment: What error?????

Comment: What is the context for your question - is this from an exam or instructional book? What research have you done - did you look up the meaning of *on foot* and *by foot*? What did you find? If you're not fluent in English, have you considered [ell.se] as a more suitable site? :-)

Comment: There is no error.